# Who is manufacturing the solar panels for the Inmarsat Elera satellites?

Tags: solar-power, manufacturing

We would like to estimate whether extreme geomagnetic storms would cause any trouble to the solar panels of Elera satellites.

Comment: If I understand correctly Elera is a payload aboard the [Inmarsat 6 satellites](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/inmarsat-6.htm) used for [L-band low bandwidth M2M, IOT and other mobile data applications](https://www.inmarsatgov.com/capabilities/inmarsat-l-band/) There was a serious anomaly with [Inmarsat-6 F2](https://www.satellitetoday.com/technology/2023/08/24/inmarsat-6-f2-satellite-suffers-unprecedented-anomaly/) In the future the Inmarsat-8 fleet will extend coverage for these kinds of communications.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inmarsat I think you can adjust your question to ask about the sensitivity of the solar panels of modern satellite bus systems in GEO to solar storms in general. I don't think the solar panels are what is the main concern for solar storms, and spacecraft in GEO are so far away from Earth that [**geo**magnetic storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm#Satellite_hardware_damage) associated with Earth's magnetosphere  are not an issue.

Comment: The title and the body of the question seem to be about two completely different things.

Comment: Extreme storms in excess of design criteria are likely to do bad things.

Comment: Airbus Defence and Space (formerly Astrium) developed the solar panels. Being entirely electric the route to GEO is about 3-6 months as opposed to a week under chemical. That meant there were two areas to look at concerning the panels - extended thermal exposure during the trip (apply localized heaters) - and extended radiation exposure, through particles trapped in the Van Allen belt and solar proton events. ELERA just seems to be the name applied to the L-band network, which is part of a larger project called Orchestra, which includes additional satellites in other orbits including LEO.